# How to get the name of the layer on a map composer with a single layer?

Tags: qgis, labeling, print-composer, expression, qgis-2.14

I tried

```
layer_property( 'layer', 'title')
```

I would like to return the current layer from the map instead of 'layer'.
(or list of the layers on the map?)

Doesn't seems to works with

```
 layer_id
```

or

```
@layer_name
```

It's for a model composer, that's why i want it dynamics.

Comment: did you find a solution? Have a similar challenge now.

Comment: Nope, I leff this idea, and i did it brutal : writing each time this info. May be with the new version, currently using las palmas, apparently there is a variable attached with the layer : "layer_id" But i'm not expert with expression...